# InstallShield - Suddenly incorrect path to InstallUtilLib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I have experienced the famous error 1001 today. The reason for this, was apparently that the .NET Framework File Locations for InstallShield LE were changed to the path of .NET 4.0 even though the project is just using .Net 3.5 .

Does anyone know why this setting was changed? I am suspecting that a Windows Update for the .NET Framework might have caused this.
It took quite some time to figure this out, so I would like know what the actual cause was and how I can prevent it from happening again.

For those of you who should stumble upon this and have the same problem, it can be easily fixed (tested in Visual Studio 2012 and InstallShield LE). Run Visual Studio as admin and go to the InstallShield LE tab. Select "Options" and go to the ".NET" tab. Now select the correct path for your .NET Framework according to the version you use in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself, the (in)famous 1001 error.  Do yourself a favor and switch to WiX ToolSet's  Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) managed custom actions.  You can encapsulate this in a WiX merge module project and then consume the merge module in your InstallShield LE project.   It's such a better design pattern.

One of the really nice things about DTF is you can compile a custom action for .NET 2.0 and include a CustomAction.Config that allows it to bind to CLR 2.0 or 4.0.  This makes it practically bulletproof from XP to Windows 10.

Aren't your users important enough to make sure they never see a 1001 error?  Isn't your help desk important enough to make sure they don't get those calls?  Isn't your brand important enough to make sure that users don't post your product sucks on social media?

Comment: You have a notorious reputation to comment and answer against the use of custom actions. The cause for this was not in any way related to custom actions, but to changed settings. The question is, what changed these settings automatically or what could have been a source of this? The problem could also occur for pretty much every other tool if something causes changes to settings. The usage of tool sets is not the topic of the question.

Comment: It's completely related. My answer wasn't to not use custom actions, it was to use better custom actions.  Now if you told me what your custom action did I might very well be able to point out a better way that didn't involve the use of custom actions.  As to your question of "why" the setting was changed... well  my build machines have snapshots that I can revert to to profile exactly this kind of problem.  Then again using a different pattern wouldn't leave you vulnerable to this kind of issue. I apologize for actually trying to help you with an answer that you aren't at a level to accept.

Comment: Then please explain how the usage of a different pattern would solve a configuration issue that was not caused by changes in the project or any code of the project at all? I appreciate that you want to show, that there is a better way by using WiX and DTF, but that wasn't the question. You answer just didn't provide any information to my problem.   I would also suggest to not use rhetoric questions which aim at making me feel bad. That doesn't make a good impression and makes you look like advertising WiX. I am open to honest answers and criticism.

Comment: BTW because you asked, the custom action is just a non fancy installation of a service. Really just the installation, just making sure the service starts with the correct rights, how it's named and when it is supposed to start.

Comment: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html ( note: newer versions of iswix now have a services designer )